# Appending 2d char array with 1d char array (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, string

If I have,

```
matrix1[4][4] = { 'a','b','c','d',
                  'e','f','g','h',
                  'i','j','k','l',
                  'm','n','o','p'}

string1[50] = "text"
```

how do you go about adding a character from the matrix into the string?
like if I wanted "g" added to "text" to make like string2 = textg

strcat doesn't take these parameters. Can I do something like making a separate char string2 = matrix1[2][3] and append that to string1? But what if i want more than 1 char like g and k to make textgk.

Comment: `strncat(string1, matrix1[1][2], 1);strncat(string1, matrix1[2][2], 1);` or `char string2[50]; snprintf(string2, sizeof(string2), "%s%c%c", string1, matrix1[1][2], matrix1[2][2]);`. note matrix1[1][2] : 'g' , matrix1[2][2] : 'k',  matrix1[2][3] : 'l'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign it directly

```
text[4] = matrix [2][3];
text [5] = '\0';
```

Or you can do something like this.

```
 void appendChar(char * pString, char c)
{
    int len = strlen (pString);
    pString[len] = c;
    pString [len +1] = '\0';

}

appendChar (string1, matrix [2][3]);
```

Of course this function assumes pString points to a buffer big enough to hold the character to be appended.